# regularity of the solutions of Prandtl equation on the segment

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus

Let $p(x)$ be a positive measurable function on $(-1,1)$. Consider the Prandtl equation
$$
u(x)-\frac{p(x)}\pi \int_{-1}^1 \frac{u'(t)}{t-x}dt=p(x)h_0(x),\quad u(1)=u(-1)=0.\quad\quad(\star)
$$
What is state of the art of the existsence and regularity theory for $(\star)$, what is a standard reference?
Recall that $(\star)$ may be rewritten as $u+p(x)\sqrt{-d^2/dx^2}u=p(x)h_0(x)$, where $-d^2/dx^2$ is Dirichlet Laplacian on $[-1,1]$, that relates this to the regularity theory for fractional Laplacians.

Comment: For the fractional Laplacian formulation: for the existence, one can refer, for example, to the 20-year-old paper by K. Bogdan and T. Byczkowski [*Potential theory of Schrödinger operator based on fractional Laplacian*](https://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~pms/files/20.2/Article/20.2.6.pdf). Regularity might be treated in a much more recent paper [*The fractional Schrödinger equation with general nonnegative potentials. The weighted space approach*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08398) by J.I. Díaz, D. Gómez-Castro and J.L. Vázquez. The latter is purely analytic and gives a lot of references.

Answer (score 1):

With $q=1/p$, let me write your equation as
$$
\vert D\vert u+ q u= h_0, \quad u(\pm 1)=0.
$$
Multiplying the equation by $u$, we get
$$\Vert{u}\Vert_{H^{1/2}_0}^2\le
\Vert{u}\Vert_{H^{1/2}_0}^2+\underbrace{\langle qu, u\rangle_{L^2}}_{\ge 0}=\langle h_0, u\rangle_{L^2}\le \Vert{u}\Vert_{H^{1/2}_0}\Vert{h_0}\Vert_{H^{-1/2}}, 
$$
entailing
$
\Vert{u}\Vert_{H^{1/2}_0}\le \Vert{h_0}\Vert_{H^{-1/2}}.
$
Assuming $h_0\in H^{-1/2}$ will give $u$ in $H^{1/2}_0$ (completion of smooth compactly functions supported in $(-1,1)$ for the $H^{1/2}$ norm; here $H^{-1/2}$ stands for the dual space of $H^{1/2}_0$). With no more information on the regularity of $1/p$, it seems questionable to improve the regularity $H^{1/2}$.